# Changing opacity and text color with jquery

Tags: jquery, opacity

Hopefully this question isn't too silly...I'm still a beginner!

I'm trying to build my portfolio site right now, it can be seen at [hellothisis.cc](http://www.hellothisis.cc)

My goal is to get the copyright symbol to be at full opacity for a few seconds, then lower to .1 opacity which I believe I did successfully. The code might be ghetto but it works? I also wanted it to have a hover property that changes the copyright symbol to full opacity red when hovered over, and then goes back to the faded out gray when you move the mouse.

Here is my code so far, including the hide and click function that the copyright symbol has.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".name").delay(1000).fadeTo('slow', 0.1, function() {
         $(".name").hover(function() {
             $(this).animate({ opacity: 1 });
             });
      });
    });

    $('.bio').hide();
    $('.name').click(function(){
        $('.bio').fadeToggle(1000);
    });
</script>
```

My problem right now is that after you hover over the faded gray, it remains at full opacity even after you move your mouse off of it? Any help would be very much appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Bind directly, you don't need to wait the delay+fadeto is complete for that (+if someone mouseover during that fadeto it will come back to opacity 1 which is more logical imo

```
 $(".name").on({
          mouseover : function(e) {
                   $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1 });
         },
          mouseout : function(e) {
                   $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.1 });
          }
 }).delay(1000).fadeTo('slow', 0.1);
```

edit : chain in order

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$(".name").hover(function() {
  $(this).animate({ opacity: 1 });
}, function(){
  $(this).animate({ opacity: .1 });
});
```

The first function is used when the `mouseenter` event fires, the second when the `mouseleave` event is called.

But I'd suggest looking into [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for the future as it will serve you better.